# CSS users abusing [inline] tag

Tags: discussion, retag-request

There's a solid  554 questions tagged with [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css)[inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inline).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inline+css

[inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inline), however, describes the concept of an `inline` function, e.g. in [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c):

> An inline function is a function upon which the compiler has been requested to perform inline expansion. In other words, the programmer has requested that the compiler insert the complete body of the function in every place that the function is called, rather than generating code to call the function in the one place it is defined. (However, compilers are not obligated to respect this request.)

I've yet to find a single one of these that is actually about inline function.

They are all about layouting things. Which is nice, but proves none of these authors read the [inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inline) excerpt (or they didn't care, or didn't understand, one or a combination of these).

I think the right reaction would be to simply remove all the [inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inline) from these >500 questions automatically, but I can also see that one might want to have something like [inline-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inline-layout) or so.

Comment: There is [inline-styles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inline-styles) so they can be migrate to this tag insted

Comment: "inline-styles" is **not** related to "inline-layout"...which would be a better fit.

Comment: At that point I should ask, do we really need any of this?

Comment: @Braiam No, we don't need [tag:inline-styles] or [tag:inline-layout].

Comment: @Braiam good point. Even without that tag, people will search for "CSS inline", and will still find those posts.

Comment: @TylerH: [inline-styles] is fine, considering there's an [entire CSS module](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr) devoted to inline styles.

Comment: @BoltClock You've gone to the dark side

Comment: I'm against [inline-layout], that should be covered by [css-display] or [css-box-model], which should not be synonyms of [css]. There are two entire [CSS Display](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3) and [CSS basic box model](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-box) modules which are being ignored.

Comment: Don't blame just the CSS users for that. [inline] was a terrible choice of name for a tag by whoever created it in my opinion. It's a word with so many different applications across several fields it should have been qualified with something like [inline-functions]. That would have avoided this problem.

Comment: Agree. [inline] is a meta-tag. Burninate.

Comment: @michaelb958 Thou should be posting this as an answer, I think

Comment: I didn't because I'm not on SO very much these days, and had only done a one-minute analysis of the problem.

Comment: @michaelb958 in that case: I'm doing your work, but don't blame me for giving it my spin :)

Answer (score 3):

@michaelb [made](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332086/css-users-abusing-inline-tag#comment381874_332086) the following statement, agreeing with [@ivarni](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332086/css-users-abusing-inline-tag#comment381868_332086):

> Agree. [inline] is a meta-tag. Burninate.

basing on the arguing that:

> [inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inline) was a terrible choice of name for a tag by whoever created it in my opinion. It's a word with so many different applications across several fields it should have been qualified with something like [inline-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inline-functions). That would have avoided this problem.

To me this sounds like this is a recommendation to retag all [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)+[inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inline), [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)[inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inline) questions as [inline-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inline-function), and then get rid of the tag, speedily going through the [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css)+[inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inline) posts, analysing shortly if additional tagging is required – since [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) kind of implies the question might be about layout.